# How do I permanently allow a website to access my location?

Tags: safari, geolocation

In iOS, I only need to be asked once whether I want to allow a website to share my location data. Is it possible to permanently do this in OS X version of Safari as well?

[image]

Comment: HERE'S THE CORRECT MODERN ANSWER:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/307583/19991

Comment: Even more modern  # https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/467092/138603

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your Safari preferences  > Privacy :

Select **Prompt for each website one time only**

[image]

Comment: It appears that this option is not available in Safari 11 on macOS High Sierra ☹️

Comment: It’s sort of still present; the whole approach has been redesigned, so you now set your preference on a site-by-site basis. Check Preferences → Websites → Location and then change the setting for the desired site to _Allow_.

Comment: On Safari 11 its Safari -> 'Settings for this Website' instead of 'Safari -> Preferences'

Comment: now totally, completely different in 2018, see linked