# How to permanently allow location access for a website in Safari 11?

Tags: safari, high-sierra

The method mentioned in this question no longer works:
[How do I permanently allow a website to access my location?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/122930/how-do-i-permanently-allow-a-website-to-access-my-location)

Is there some way to achieve the same effective in High Sierra?

Answer (score 6):

**Open the website** you want to permanently allow.

- Go to Safari preferences at top left under Safari.
- Click on Website tab.
- Click on **Locations tab on left side**.
- On currently opened websites, select Allow on the one that you want to permanently allow.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Slightly updated for Sonoma 14.1.2 (late 2023):

1. Safari > Settings
2. "Websites" tab
3. "Location" in the side panel
4. Pick between "Ask", "Allow" and "Deny" per website

This is what it looks like with a couple of tabs open:

[image]