# How to Stop Website Requests for Location

Tags: macos, safari

This is macOS 10.12.6 and Safari 11.1.

Frequently when accessing a website new to me, I am presented with this dialog:

[image]

In System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy, the checkbox for Safari is unchecked, presumably blocking this sort of request...but they keep appearing.

Is there another setting I've missed (perhaps in Safari preferences), or some other way to block these Location requests or to mandate a default "Don't Allow?" I think this could be done by turning off Location Services entirely, but then I'd lose "Find My Mac" which I'd like to retain.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/122932/126929 — Check the second comment.

Comment: Thanks, @Joonas. I have the checkbox at the bottom of that Safari Preferences tab unchecked, but websites still pop up asking. And the websites that pop up and ask are not listed at that Safari Preferences tab, even after I've hit "Deny" in the dialog. And even if the prohibition on the Preferences page worked, there doesn't appear to be a way to add websites to the list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In **Safari 11.1** Preferences > Websites > Location. Bottom right of the window, change "When visiting other websites:" select *Deny*. This will block all websites and you can white list specific sites in the above list.

You can also *right click the address bar* and select "Settings for this website" to get to the same options.